# Powershell script to automate gci

Tags: powershell

I'm tying to automate gci in order to work on each row in a config file, where for each row I have as first column the path, and following it a list of files. Something like this:

```
C:\Users\*\AppData\Roaming\* *.dll
C:\Test file.txt,file2.txt
```

This means that gci will search for:
*.dll in C:\Users*\AppData\Roaming*
file.txt in C:\Test
file2.txt in C:\Test

In order to do this I'm creating dynamically the where condition in the script below. Here the ps script I'm using

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\List.txt) {
       
    try {
        $path,$files = $line.split(' ')
        $files = $files.split(',')
    }
    catch {
        $path = $line
        $files = "*.*"
    }
        
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($files)){
        $files = "*.*"
    }
    
    $filter = $files -join(" -or `$_.Name` -like ")
    $filter = "`$_.Name` -like " + $filter
                
    echo "Searching Path: $path, Pattern: $filter" | out-file -append -encoding ASCII -filepath .\result.txt
        
    if ($path.Contains("*"))
    {
        gci -Path $path -Recurse | Where {$filter} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Out-String -Width 2048 | out-file -append -encoding UTF8 -filepath .\result.txt
    }
    else
    {
        gci -Path $path | Where {$filter} | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Out-String -Width 2048 | out-file -append -encoding UTF8 -filepath .\result.txt
    }
}
```

The problem is that the where filter is not considered. All files are returned

**First attempt**, suggested by

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\List.txt) {
    try {
        $path,$files = $line.split(' ')
        $files = $files.split(',')
    }
    catch {
        $path = $line
        $files = "*.*"
    }
        
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($files)){
        $files = "*.*"
    }

    $filter = $files -join(" -or `$_.Name -like ")
    $filter = "`$_.Name -like " + $filter 

    $gciParams = @{
        Path = $Path
        Recurse = $Path.Contains('*')
    }

    "Searching Path: $path, Pattern(s): [$($files -join ',')]" | Add-Content -Path .\result.txt -Encoding ASCII
        
    Get-ChildItem @gciParams | Where $filter | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Add-Content -Path .\result.txt -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Comment: All the power of .net objects at your fingertips and you choose to make it harder on yourself by making everything strings. Have you tried making your where filter with the curly braces and without the backticks?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it's my very first attempt to powershell. so I don't have a good idea of what you're talking about. Do you have a reference showing your suggestion in practice? Thanks for your answer

Comment: Consider using the `-Include` parameter instead of the `-Filter` parameter...

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I've modified into gci -Path $path -Recurse -Include {$filter} but still no success. Now I have no results

Comment: The use of `-Include` would obviate the need to build a filter expression; simply pass the file list to the `-Include`: If the line from the config file is in `$line`, you should be able to do something like `$rootdir,$filelist = $line -split ' '; Get-ChildItem -Path $rootdir -Include $filelist`.

Comment: Note that this is somewhat simplistic; it will fail if the path itself has a space in it.

Comment: Correction: `$rootdir,$filelist = $line -split ' '; $rootdir = $rootdir + "\*"; Get-ChildItem -Path $rootdir -Include $filelist`

Comment: @JeffZeitlin indeed the choice of " " (space) as separator was not very wise. I'll chose something like | instead. Thanks again for your support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to create a piece of code and *defer execution of it until later*, you need a [Script Block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_script_blocks).

A Script Block *literal* in PowerShell is just `{}`, so for constructing script block to filter based on a single comparison, you'd want to define `$filter` like this:

```
$filter = {$_.Name -like $filter}
```

At which point you can pass it directly as an argument to `Where-Object`:

```
Get-ChildItem $path |Where-Object $filter
```

... but since you want to test against *multiple* wildcard patterns, we'll need to write a slightly different filtering routine:

```
$filter = {
  # Store file name of file we're filtering
  $FileName = $_.Name

  # Test ALL the patterns in $files and see if at least 1 matches
  $files.Where({$FileName -like $_}, 'First').Count -eq 1
}
```

Since the `$filter` block now references `$files` to get the patterns, we can simplify your loop as:

```
foreach($line in Get-Content .\List.txt) {
    try {
        $path,$files = $line.split(' ')
        $files = $files.split(',')
    }
    catch {
        $path = $line
        $files = "*.*"
    }
        
    if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($files)){
        $files = "*.*"
    }

    $gciParams = @{
        Path = $Path
        Recurse = $Path.Contains('*')
    }

    "Searching Path: $path, Pattern(s): [$($files -join ',')]" | Add-Content -Path .\result.txt -Encoding ASCII
        
    Get-ChildItem @gciParams | Where $filter | Select -ExpandProperty FullName | Add-Content -Path .\result.txt -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Note that we no longer need to re-define `$filter` everytime the loop runs - the condition is based on the value of `$files` at runtime, so you can define `$filter` once before entering the loop and then reuse `$filter` every time.

The "trick" with using `@gciParams` (which allows us to remove the big `if/else` block) is known as [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting), but you could achieve the same result with `Get-ChildItem -Path:$Path -Recurse:$Path.Contains('*')` :)

Comment: Not sure to have understood the application of your solution, I edited my question and addd a first solution attempt, but it didn't work

Comment: @gipinani No, my answer was incomplete, I've updated it :)